# Firestore Increment not working in Python code

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Python application that uses Google Firestore as its database. One of the features of the application contains incrementing a field value in a Firestore document by a certain amount. For this purpose, I am using the Increment class provided by the Firestore API. However, tests show that the value is not being incremented.

To isolate the issue, I have written a PoC test that sets the field value to 0 and then increments it by 1 using Increment. Here is the relevant code snippet of the test:

Here is the relevant code snippet of my test:

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase

from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import Increment, Client
from google.oauth2 import credentials

EMULATOR_HOST = "127.0.0.1:8080"


class TestE2EFieldValues(TestCase):
    def test_field_values(self):
        os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = EMULATOR_HOST
        firestore_client = Client(credentials=credentials.credentials.AnonymousCredentials())

        firestore_client.collection("test").document("test").set({"test_increment": 0})
        firestore_client.collection("test").document("test").update({"test_increment": Increment(1)})
        updated_item = firestore_client.collection("test").document("test").get()

        self.assertEqual(updated_item.get("test_increment"), 1)
```

As you can see, I am using the Increment class to increment the field value, and then retrieving the updated value using get(). However, the value remains at 0 and the test fails with the following assertion error:

`AssertionError: 0 != 1`

I have verified that the Firestore emulator is running and accessible and that the Client is properly authenticated using anonymous credentials. I have also tried using FieldValue.increment(1) instead of Increment(1), but the result is the same.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Am I missing something in my code or in my setup? Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.